# Express extensibility with stacking higher-order functions or RWS monad transformer?

Tags: haskell, user-interface, functional-programming, monad-transformers

I'm working on a basic UI toolkit. It only consists of align and rasterisation functions at the moment.

I am trying to to make it extensible and clear. I found two ways to do that, but I am not sure / could not find out which one is better.

Web Application Interface (WAI) uses a structure similar to:

```
type CUI = Event -> State UI Picture 
type Middleware = CUI -> CUI -- cool stackable stuff
```

Using RWS and RWST gives something similar:

```
newtype RWSUI a = RWSUI (RWS Event Picture UI a)
newtype Middleware m a = Middleware (RWST Event Picture UI (RWST Event Picture UI m) a)
```

Monad transformers are still something blurry for my eyes. RWS might be a clearer way to express extensibility in the long run, but the WAI way seems sufficient. I can't get a clear choice out of it. Any suggestions on how to decide this?